# Is there a way to create multiple nested lists to a certain depth?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I apologise if the question is indirect or confusing. What I'm trying to achieve is a list like the one below:

```
[[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]]
```

However, I want the list to have a variable amount of list "depth" (the above list has a list "depth" of 3 since it a maximum of 3 lists at the bottom; to access an item in it it would look like `` `aList[1][0][1]` `` )

I have tried using list comprehension:

```
aList = [[[[None for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
```

The only problem with this is that I can't change the depth of the list without directly editing the code.

What can I do to achieve the result I'm after? (The list I am trying to achieve contains 7^4 (2401) items, just so you're aware.)

Comment: The list comprehension will become incomprehensible pretty quickly.  It sounds like a good job for a recursive function ..

Comment: Shall the lists have the same size or different sizes?

Comment: @KellyBundy different sizes. the width and depth of the lists have to be variable.

Comment: Hmm, that's unclear. What are the width and depth of the lists in your first example? (The `[[[0,0], ...` one).

Comment: @KellyBundy a depth of 3, and the widths are different for each level. 3 for the first, 3 for the next, and 2 for the last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a nice job for [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
import numpy as np

out = np.zeros((3, 3, 2), dtype=int).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], 
 [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

Or with a recursive function:

```
def nested(shape):
    if shape:
        n, *shape = shape
        return [nested(shape) for _ in range(n)]
    return 0

out = nested((3, 3, 2))
```

Comment: just to confirm, i can pass in (3, 3, 2) as a tuple?

Comment: @iCxbe yes `shape` should be a tuple (or iterable)

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is your friend:

```
def nested_list(depth, size):
    if depth == 1:
        return [None for _ in range(size)]
    return [nested_list(depth-1, size) for _ in range(size)]
```

Comment: Can't produce their first example, as their sizes aren't all the same.

Answer (score 0):

## Pure python solution

My recommendation: only if you can't use numpy.

### Recursion

Warning, this code is simple but have a depth limit depending on your configuration.

```
from pprint import pprint


def list_in_depth_recursive(depth: int, length: int | None = None):
    """limited by stack size (default 500 or 1000)"""
    if length is None:
        length = depth

    if depth <= 1:
        return [None] * length

    return [list_in_depth_recursive(depth - 1, length) for _ in range(length)]


pprint(list_in_depth_recursive(3))
# [[[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]],
#  [[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]],
#  [[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]]
```

```py
>>> pprint(list_in_depth_recursive(10000))
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

### Iterative

Warning, because of the `deepcopy`, you can also produce a `RecursionError` with this code.

```py
from copy import deepcopy
from pprint import pprint


def list_in_dept_iterative(depth: int, length: int | None = None):
    """limited by memory"""
    if length is None:
        length = depth

    if depth <= 0:
        return [None]

    current_depth_list = [None] * length
    while depth > 1:
        current_depth_list = [deepcopy(current_depth_list) for _ in range(length)]
        depth -= 1
    return current_depth_list


pprint(list_in_dept_iterative(3))
# [[[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]],
#  [[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]],
#  [[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]]
```

Comment: the list im after is actually pretty big (7^4 = 2401) so im not sure if recursion would be acceptable. thank you though.

Comment: @iCxbe Hmm? Do you mean 7×7×7×7 like your first example is 3×3×2? Then that's not "pretty big" but really *small*, and none of the solutions would have the slightest problem with it. Do you mean something else?

Comment: list_in_depth_recursive(4, 7) is not an issue. It is if you need a depth of 500 or 1000+ only. list_in_depth_recursive(1000) is usually the limit, so a much bigger list, 1000^1000.

Comment: @DorianTurba oh alright, that was just a case of me not understanding the issue. thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive approach with `reduce`

```
from functools import reduce

shape = 3, 2, 5
lst = reduce(lambda row, dim: row + [[0] * dim], shape, [])
#[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is probably your best bet for this:

```
def matrix(size,*more):
    return [matrix(*more) for _ in range(size)] if more else [0]*size
```

output:

```
matrix(3,3,2)

[[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

You could also do it iteratively by splitting an initial 1D list to break it down for each dimension:

```
def matrix(*dims):
    result = [0]
    for d in dims: result *= d
    for d in dims[:0:-1]:
        result = [ result[i:i+d] for i in range(0,len(result),d) ]
    return result
```

Answer (score -2):

We can multiply if we deduplicate via string:

```
a = eval(str([[[0]*2]*3]*3))
```

For variable sizes like `sizes = 2, 3, 3`:

```
n = len(sizes)
a = eval(str(eval('[' * n + '0' + ']*%d' * n % sizes)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/vzizKrVYwVbBSEfBGIi4uPKAnJzUPA2whCZXIpCbWpaYo1FcUqQBZqhHq2vlKWgrqBuog8hYLdUUoIAqRL2mJhdXYrRBLAQB9RoaGZtwFRRl5pVoAI2yVYiOjgYJ6RjE6kQbwEkghcTDIxar@f8/AA)

Comment: i think the issue with this is that the values all point to the same areas, so when i would try to change a single value, multiple values would change at once, and that's not what im after.

Comment: @iCxbe That's not true. The deduplication fixes that. It's also hard to overlook the deduplication code, *and* I explicitly pointed it out in the text.

Comment: still, theres another issue. what if i want the depth to change through the change of a single variable? this has a fixed depth, and it wouldn't be easy to change it without directly editing the code itself. provide a solution to this if possible, given that i did specify that the depth has to be variable.

Comment: @iCxbe Ah yes, that is a real issue. I actually started with a variable version and then apparently forgot about that. It was late last night. I'll add a variable one.